# How to run airflow dag on working days between 9am to 4pm in every 10 minutes

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I have a DAG that needs to be scheduled to run in working days (Mon to Fri) between 9AM to 4PM in every 10 minutes. How do i do this in Airflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your DAG with cron expression: `*/10 9-16 * * 1-5` Which *means at every 10th minute past every hour from 9 through 16 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday*. See [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/10_9-16_*_*_1-5).

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval='*/10 9-16 * * 1-5',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
)
```

Comment: @Amitjoc did it solve your issue?

Comment: Yeah it is working for me thanks Elad